# D disabling struct from being lvalue

Tags: variables, struct, d, lvalue

Is there any way to disable a struct from being used as an lvalue (cannot be used as a variable)?

I've tried disabling constructors and opAssign, but in the end, you can still assign it from functions.

```
unittest
{
    //mystruct doesntCompile;
    mystruct shouldntCompile = makeMyStruct();
}


struct mystruct
{
    @disable this();
    @disable this(this);
    @disable void opAssign(ref mystruct);
    @disable void opAssign(mystruct);
    this(int dummyArgument){}
}

mystruct makeMyStruct()
{
    return mystruct(0);
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `const` keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to disable a struct from being used as an lvalue (cannot be used as a variable)?

No, it's not possible. Every type can have instances that are lvalues.

You may get better answers if you [let us know what you are trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/143209). *Why* do you want to prevent your struct from being used as an lvalue?

Comment: The question was mostly morbid curiosity.

Comment: The original problem was implementing a vector struct with swizzles which you can use all operators on (including opOpAssign). This we have now achieved using a proxy struct. The proxy struct shouldn't be used as a variable in itself, but only exist temporarily in an expression. You shouldn't be able to do this:

`auto proxy = vec.xyz;
proxy.x = 5; //Changes vec.x`

Since this would invalidate the value type expectation. The current implementation uses a union inside the proxy.

Comment: Ok, so is the problem that you are able to write through the proxy? Am I allowed to read? If you share up the implementation of proxy and state exactly how it is meant to be used I'm pretty sure I can help. What your question asks does not seem to be what you need to do.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The user should be able to read the values of the original vector, but only assign to them using a single expression.


Example of intended usage:
`vec1.zw += vec2.zw + vec3.yz;//All swizzles are proxies`

My simple hope was that by denying lvalue usage we could get assignments like `auto proxy = vec.xyz;` to default to `alias makeVector this`.

Thank you for your offer of help, but the code is not yet fit for public inspection. Besides, I more or less have faith in my ability to see this one through. :)